# How to get field values of a just created (or not yet) node?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am calling `node_load()` function in a custom module and it returns only part of the variables like `title`, `uid`, `vid`, `status` (all the meta), but it never returns actual field contents. I tried `node_page_view()`, tried `menu_get_object()` - all in vain, no field values.

What am I doing wrong? Is this because maybe my module is calling `node_load()` too early before the saving node, but then how it has already `$node->title`, `$node->nid` and other values? If they are some kind of prepared values, then how can I get the same prepared value for a custom field?

And here is the code from the Community documentation page [Sending Notification Messages](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180227) that I am using in my module:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function foo_node_insert($node) {

  $message = message_create('foo_message_type', array('uid' => $node->uid));

  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('message', $message);
  $wrapper->field_node_ref->set($node);

  $options = array(
     'rendered fields' => array(
       'message_notify_email_subject' => 'field_rendered_subject',
       'message_notify_email_body' => 'field_rendered_body',
     ),
  );

  message_notify_send_message($message, $options);
}
```

and it works just fine for the message subject, however for some reason I can't get node body to be mailed properly.

I tried to see the content of the $node variable in the following code from example module:

```
elseif (isset($message['params']['message_entity']->field_node_ref)) {
    // This is a node.
    $nid = $message['params']['message_entity']->field_node_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $messageid_params['uid'] = $node->uid;
    $messageid_params['nid'] = $node->nid;
    $messageid_params['cid'] = 0;
    $messageid_params['time'] = $node->created;
    if (variable_get('mailcomment_alter_subjects', 1)) {
      $subject = $message['subject'];
      $subject = variable_get('site_name', '') ? '[' . variable_get('site_name', '') . '] ' . $node->title : $subject;
      $message['subject'] = $subject;
    }
    dpm($node);
   }
```

and unfortunately my custom node field always returns empty:

```
field_description (Array, 0 elements)
$...->field_description
```

Comment: `hook_node_insert`is invoked from `node_save()` after the database query that will insert the node into the node table is scheduled for execution, after the type-specific `hook_insert()` is invoked, and after `field_attach_insert()` is called. Therefore, the node is already created. Is there a way that you can show your code?

Comment: You should show the code you are using. `node_load()` loads the values from the database, but it stores the value in a temporary cache too. I have never seen the behaviour you are seeing, thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that I needed to do was using

```
$node = node_load($nid, null, true);
```

instead of just

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

and now the node is loading as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
hook_entity_postinsert();
```

from the [Hook Post Action module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action). It loads field values always by [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I don't see how can I use that function in my example. My module does not create a node, it just retrieves node information from $message variable. Please see https://www.drupal.org/node/2180227